My Mint Authority for my memecoin was giving to Systems program 11111111111111111111111111111111,Can it be fixed?
So I made a memecoin 8 months back, The mint authority was giving to System program 11111111111111. Dextools, Dexscreener,Birdeye.so all show my coin is unmintable,But lately some programs like sol sniffer and other bots are showing it is mintable. Im on the Jupiter Strictlist to ,but is there anything I can do to fix this I still have update authority. Here is my Solscan page. Could someone also answer what System Program is? Thanks.
https://solscan.io/token/A6YRaK4toMe2qZY7KLNCugXBrsjCG4fAjAR8uZUBeUek

The System Program is responsible to creating new accounts on Solana and owns all accounts on Solana.
Since it's now the mint authority, you'd need it to sign so that you can get back this authority, which is impossible to do.

Thank You, For explaining appreciate it!
